# SAP and PeopleSoft using web service complex object

Tags: .net, web-services, sap, peoplesoft

We are creating a web service that will take a complex object as a parameter. Will this be an issue if SAP and PeopleSoft need to consume the service and create the object to pass in as a parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like you to describe the webservice with many details (SOAP, REST, data format, security protocols, etc.), and tell more about which SAP software/programming language/version is to consume this webservice (same for Peoplesoft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the WSDL is well-established, and both PeopleSoft and SAP can create SOAP XML requests and send them to a URL, then both should be able to work with your service.

The key will be marshalling and unmarshalling your complex object to and from XML.  Neither PeopleSoft nor SAP will be able to deal with your object.  They'll have to get everything they need from XML, no more and no less.

Start by establishing the contract for request and response for your service, and the rest will follow: [contract first web service.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html)

Comment: So this is not something that will be easy to do by a non developer who administers SAP?